# Can we use an observer in an observer?

Tags: android, android-room, viewmodel, observers

Hello everyone I am faced with the following problem. I have a database Room, I have 2 tables POST_TABLE and SELL_TABLE.

Now I need to get data from two tables and add to the arraylist.
I use the observer to track when **the sell items** are loaded and then add  it to the arraylist and same I do to **the post items**

I do this to show two different view types objects in recycler view.

In ViewModel everything is simple, I get access to the database, receive sell and post **DAO** and initialize repository.

It seems to me I'm doing wrong to make the observer in the observer in home fragment.

*In the best practice I did not find a suitable answer. Maybe somebody knows how to reach data from room correctly?*

```
From HomeFragment

private fun initObserver() {
        viewModel.sellList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            viewModel.addSellItemsToArray()
            
            viewModel.postList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
                viewModel.addPostItemToArray()
                
                initRecyclerView(viewModel.homeArrayList)
            })
        })
    }
```

```
From ViewModel

private val sellRepository: SellRepository
    private val postRepository: PostRepository

    var sellList: LiveData<List<Sell>>
    var postList: LiveData<List<Post>>
    private var _homeItem = MutableLiveData<ArrayList<HomeItem>>().apply {
        value = arrayListOf()
    }
    val homeItem get() = _homeItem

    val homeArrayList = arrayListOf<HomeItem>()


    init {
        val sellDao = MainDatabase.getDatabase(application).sellDao()
        val postDao = MainDatabase.getDatabase(application).postDao()

        sellRepository = SellRepository(sellDao)
        postRepository = PostRepository(postDao)

        sellList = sellRepository.getAllSellList()
        postList = postRepository.getPostList()

    }

    fun addSellItemsToArray() {
        for (sell in sellList.value!!) {
            val homeItem = HomeItem()
            homeItem.userName = sell.userName
            homeItem.userImage = sell.userImage
            homeItem.imagesArray = sell.imagesArray
            homeItem.desc = sell.desc
            homeItem.itemForSell = sell.itemForSell
            homeItem.price = sell.price
            homeItem.country = sell.country
            homeItem.city = sell.city
            homeItem.address = sell.address

            homeArrayList.add(homeItem)
        }
    }

    fun addPostItemToArray() {
        for (post in postList.value!!) {
            val homeItem = HomeItem()
            homeItem.userName = post.postedUserName
            homeItem.userImage = post.userUrl
            homeItem.imagesArray = arrayListOf(post.postUrl)
            homeItem.desc = post.commit
            homeItem.likesCount = post.likesCount

            homeArrayList.add(homeItem)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems to me I'm doing wrong to make the observer in the observer in home fragment.

Yes, there are better ways to handle this scenario.

One of this is the one below:

```
class YourViewModel() : ViewModel() {
  private val tempHomeList = mutableListOf<HomeItem>()

  private val _homeList = MutableLiveData<HomeItem>()
  val homeList: LiveData<HomeItem> = _homeList

  private lateinit var sellRepository: SellRepository
  private lateinit var postRepository: PostRepository

  init {
    val sellDao = MainDatabase.getDatabase(application).sellDao()
    val postDao = MainDatabase.getDatabase(application).postDao()

    sellRepository = SellRepository(sellDao)
    postRepository = PostRepository(postDao)
  }

  fun initList() {
    addSellItemsToArray()
    addPostItemToArray()
    _homeList.value = tempHomeList
  }

  private fun addSellItemsToArray() {
    val sellList = sellRepository.getAllSellList()
    for (sell in sellList.value!!) {
      val homeItem = HomeItem()
      homeItem.userName = sell.userName
      homeItem.userImage = sell.userImage
      homeItem.imagesArray = sell.imagesArray
      homeItem.desc = sell.desc
      homeItem.itemForSell = sell.itemForSell
      homeItem.price = sell.price
      homeItem.country = sell.country
      homeItem.city = sell.city
      homeItem.address = sell.address

      tempHomeList.add(homeItem)
    }
  }

  private fun addPostItemToArray() {
    val postList = postRepository.getPostList()
    for (post in postList.value!!) {
      val homeItem = HomeItem()
      homeItem.userName = post.postedUserName
      homeItem.userImage = post.userUrl
      homeItem.imagesArray = arrayListOf(post.postUrl)
      homeItem.desc = post.commit
      homeItem.likesCount = post.likesCount

      tempHomeList.add(homeItem)
    }
  }
}
```

Then in your Fragment do something like:

```
class YourFragment : Fragment {
 
  private val recyclerAdapter = YourRecyclerAdapter()

  override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
  ): View {
    //init your views, view model and your recycler view adapter
    //...
    recyclerView.adapter = recyclerAdapter
  }
  
  //...
  override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    viewModel.homeList.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, { list ->
      recyclerViewAdapter.updateList(list)
    })
    //start observing other liveData or do anything else here
    //....
    viewModel.initList()
  }
}
```

And a sample of your Adapter...

```
class YourRecyclerAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<HomeItemAdapter.ViewHolder> {
  private val homeList = mutableListOf<HomeItem>()

  fun updateList(list: List<HomeItem>) {
    homeList.clear()
    homeList.addAll(list)
    notifyDataSetChanged()
  }

  //.... the rest of your adapter and viewholder
}
```